# Do loops transport physically as well?

Tags: miss-peregrines-home

In [Miss Peregrine's Home For Peculiar Children](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1935859/?ref_=nv_sr_1), one of the characters at the end recounts a journey.  In the movie, it seems pretty rushed, and the character states using this loop to get to various other loops.  When stated, it sounds like the character is being physically transported from one loop entrance to the next.

Do the loops work as transporters in space as well as time?  Is this maybe covered in more detail in the book?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### No

In fact, the difficulty of inter-loop transport is one of the prime reasons for the fragmentation of the peculiar community. This is a bit of a plot point<sup>1</sup>:

> “No. That is just a symptom of our weakness. What makes us weak is
> geography. There are, by my rough estimate, some ten thousand
> peculiars in the world today. We know there must be, just as we know
> there must be other planets in the universe that harbor intelligent
> life. It is mathematically mandatory.” He smiled and sipped his tea.
> “Now just imagine ten thousand peculiars, all with astounding talents,
> all in one place and united by a common cause. They’d be a power to be
> reckoned with, no?”
>
> <sub>*Library of Souls*</sub>

It may have have been unclear in the film, but the process Jake followed was as follows:

- Find a loop that connects to the past.
- Enter the loop.
- *Leave* the loop.
- Find another loop in another geographic area that connected to  a date further back.
- Repeat.

The third step is possible because loops are not simply temporally limited, but *geographically* limited. As mentioned in the book<sup>2</sup> :

> She shifted uncomfortably. “There’s something you should know,” she
> said, “and I’m afraid it’ll make you not want to come with us.”
>
> “It won’t,” I assured her.
>
> “When we leave here, this loop will close
> behind us. It’s possible you may never be able to return to the time
> you came from. At least, not easily.”
>
> <sub>*Miss Peregrine’s Home for Peculiar Children*</sub>

What repeats is the entire day *in a specific location*, not in all the world. Thus why, of course, loop-bound peculiars stay in one place, rather than seeing the world. This is why loops have a listed location. In addition, if all the peculiars leave the *geographic* bounds of their loop, the loop collapses. We know this must be the case, because Miss Wren’s loop stayed intact when its ymbryne was taken but the peculiar animals within remained, whereas Miss Peregrine’s loop collapsed when its inhabitants left.

The aforementioned process is described in the book as “leapfrogging”:

> I reached across her and turned to a map of Greece, even more
> clustered with spirals and numbers. “But what’s the point of listing
> all these?” I said. “How would you even get to these ancient loops?”
>
> “By leapfrogging,” said Millard. “It’s a highly complex and dangerous
> undertaking, but by leapfrogging from one loop to another—a day fifty
> years in the past, for instance—then you’ll find you have access to a
> whole range of loops that have ceased to exist in the last fifty
> years. Should you have the wherewithal to travel to them, within those
> you’ll find still other loops, and so on exponentially.”
>
> <sub>*Miss Peregrine’s Home for Peculiar Children*</sub>

<sub>1: Of course, this is a later book in the series.</sub>

<sub>2: Keep in mind that the book does have several notable differences from the film, including swapping Olive and Emma and dramatically changing the ending.</sub>

Comment: There was that special house in the ditches loop that connected directly to other loops, though. Other loops that were far away, making travel in space possible.